# SQL:select values from two columns and display as one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

`LATITUDE` and `LATITUDE` are my two columns.

I have to combine these two columns into one column.

I have to combined these two columns as point values.

I tried this..,

```
SELECT `LATITUDE`, (LATITUDE) + ' ' + LONGITUDE+) AS point
FROM incident_google
```

but it is not working.

How to combine these two columns as one?

```
EX: LATITUDE= 38.8994816000000014,LONGITUDE=-76.9785097000000036
```

i need as

```
(38.8994816000000014,76.9785097000000036) as point
```

and say answer for this..,

thanks in advances.

Comment: MySQL or `SQL Server`? the two are different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use as follows,

```
 SELECT LATITUDE, concat(LATITUDE,',' ,LONGITUDE) AS point FROM incident_google
```

Refer:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm

Answer (score 0):

In mysql

```
select CONCAT(LATITUDE, ",", LONGITUDE) as point FROM incident_google
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is new in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LATITUDE, '('+Convert(varchar(30),LATITUDE) + ',' + Convert(varchar(30),LONGITUDE)+')' AS point FROM incident_google
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT '(' + convert(varchar(50),LATITUDE) + ',' + convert(varchar(50),LONGITUDE) + ')' as Point FROM incident_google